# Badge on Cart not updating itself unless I refresh the Page

Tags: reactjs

**App.js Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Products from './components/Products/Products';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';

const App = () => {


    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

    const fetchProducts = async () => {

        const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
        setProducts(data);
    };

    const fetchCart = async () => {
        setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
    };

    const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
        const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

        setCart(item.cart);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
        fetchCart();
    }, []);

    commerce.cart.empty();
    console.log(cart);

    return (
        <div>

            <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />

        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import { AppBar, Typography, Toolbar, IconButton, Badge, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core'
import { ShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons'

import useStyles from './styles'
const Navbar = ({ totalItems }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
            <AppBar position='fixed' className={classes.appBar} color='inherit' >

                <Toolbar>

                    {/* THIS WILL BE ON LEFT */}
                    <Typography variant='h6' color='inherit' className={classes.title}>
                        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/image-260nw-611143775.jpg" alt="e-commerce" className={classes.image} height="25px" />
                        E-store
                    </Typography>

                    {/* THIS IS USE TO TAKE AS MUCH SPACE AS WE WANT INORDER TO SEPERTE LEFT AND RIGHT */}
                    <div className={classes.grow} />

                    {/* FOR RIGHT PART */}
                    <div className={classes.button}>
                        <IconButton aria-label='Show Items' color='inherit'>
                            <Badge overlap="rectangular" badgeContent={totalItems} color='secondary'>
                                <ShoppingCart />


                            </Badge>
                        </IconButton>

                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </>
    )``
}

export default Navbar

**commerce.js**

import Commerce from "@chec/commerce.js";

export const commerce = new Commerce(
  "HERE_MY_API_KEY"
);
```

I am getting an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total_items')"  but everything looks good on refreshing. On clicking the button the error occurs but after refreshing, the error is gone and I can see my result.

The main problem is that I need to refresh the page. this problem also arises when I add items to the cart. The items get added but are not shown in the console.

Comment: Can you include the /lib/commerce file?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I edited my post to add the whole APP.js component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Products from './components/Products/Products';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';

const App = () => {


    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
        setProducts(data);
    };

    const fetchCart = async () => {
        const cartItems = await commerce.cart.retrieve();
        setCart(cartItems);
    };

    const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
        const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

        // I am not sure how your cart object is structured
        // but you should add the new item (item.cart)
        // to the existing elements.
        setCart((cartItems) => [...cartItems, item.cart]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
        fetchCart();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(cart);
    }, [cart]);

    // I don't know why you empty your cart.
    // explain in the comments and I'll change it if need be
    // commerce.cart.empty();
    

    return (
        <div>
         {products.length>0 && cart && cart?.total_items && (
            <>
             <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
             <Products products = {products}  onAddToCart= 
                   {handleAddToCart} />
            </>
          )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object". This is the error I am getting now. also "Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior"  and "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" these two errors are occuring now.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=377AQ0y6LPA&list=PL6QREj8te1P6wX9m5KnicnDVEucbOPsqR&index=15

Comment: This is the project I am working on.. Watch at 1:00:11. @Alex Matei

Comment: @AnubhavJoria then try writing instead of Object.keys just cart. Like so, {product.length>0 && cart && ... }. See what that gives you.

Comment: @alex-matei the main problem is when i click on the cart icon then "handleAddToCart" this function runs. I want that after this function runs i get to see my changed cart on the console. But what I am getting is "undefined" on the console and my result is displayed only when i refresh the page. Without refreshing i am not able to get my result.

Comment: @AnubhavJoria Well, there is a lot wrong with your code. I don't understand why you wrote these two lines `commerce.cart.empty(); console.log(cart);`. Also, if you want to see when the cart changes, you need to create a `useEffec`t with the cart as a dependency, and inside it add the console log. Then, regarding the `cart.empty()`, if it empties your cart, then it will empty your cart at every setState you have on the page, so that's no good either.

Comment: @AnubhavJoria I edited my post with the whole component. Hope that helps.

Comment: pls Ignore commerce.cart.empty(); I just used it once for emptying the cart so that I can start again. It was just for nothing

Comment: The main thing is when i refresh everthing is perfect but as i click the button. The app is showing white sceen when i used your code.

Comment: When used my code as shown in the tutorial :- I have done the same thing as in the tutorial but in the tutorial He is able to click button multiple times and the changes are rendered but when i click the button nothing happens then after refreshing the page i can see the changes. The main problem is why it is not refreshing and displaying the new state itself

Comment: Can it occur because of other files. also i am using react 18 and the tutorial is in react 16

Comment: @AnubhavJoria Try deleting these `{products.length>0 && cart && cart?.total_items && `

Comment: Ya I have deleted that but still when I am doing console.log(cart) and when i am clicking on button  to add the item to the cart i am getting undefined in my console. When i refresh i can see my cart printed with updated value. The main problem is why I need to refresh the page to see the updated cart details.  why on every click it is printing undefined. I  want the console to print cart with updated value automatically not manually.